# Routing based on URL parameter in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages

This is a pretty simple question but my searches aren't coming up with the expected answers. I have a URL:

```
http://localhost/customers
```

Obviously this maps to an Index.cshtml file in the "Customers" folder.

I want another URL:

```
http://localhost/customers/<CustomerID>
```

To map to another page /Customers/Detail.cshtml

How do I configure routing in .NET Core 3.0 so that a request to `http://localhost/customers/<CustomerID>` will route to Detail.cshtml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an override route in your *Details.cshtml* file:

```
@page "/customers/{id:int}"
```

You can read about override routing in Razor Pages here: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#override-routes

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for and the link helps tremendously! For future visitors, the anchor tag to link to this page looks like this: <a asp-page="/customers/detail" asp-route-id="1">